# F# deedle Series How do I get the name of the Key and Series for use in XPlot

Tags: f#, deedle, fslab

I am plotting, using XPLot, a chart of type Table. If I do not specify a Chart.WithLables then the Table uses Column1 and Column2 as headers.  My Series was created from a DataFrame (indexed on Column with header name: Date and has a Column with the header name of Close.  Here is the code for getting the Series from the data frame:

```
`let closes =  cl?Close`
```

Since I know that the 1st column in the Chart: Table is the Series Key and the second column is value(s) of the Series.  I can hard code the Chart.WithLabels as

```
// Chart type: Table of column Close 
closes
|> Chart.Table
|> Chart.WithOptions(Options(showRowNumber = true, page = "enable",    pageSize = 20)) 
|> Chart.WithLabels ["Date"; "Close"]
```

I am looking for a method to extract the name of the Key(Date) and the name of the values(Close). For a data frame I could use

```
cl.Columns.Keys
```

to get the Column headers.  I can't find any equivalent for a Series.  I would like to code the Chart.WithLabels like

```
Chart.WithLabels [closes.KeyName; closes.Name]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike a frame, Deedle series does not store a name for the key and values.

If you want to write a reusable function, you will need to pass the names as additional parameters, or you can pass a data frame with a single column to your function.

I would probably write something like:

```
let plotSeriess label data =
  data
  |> Chart.Table
  |> Chart.WithOptions(Options(showRowNumber = true, page = "enable",    pageSize = 20)) 
  |> Chart.WithLabels ["Date"; label]
```